# Redesigning an API calculation with an async queue

Tags: node.js, api, express, asynchronous

I need some help to redesign an endpoint of my API.
This endpoint triggers a calculation, composed of many API calls.

To describe this calculation :

- A user ask for a calculation with 3 geographical points (A, B, C)
- The node server ask postgis for 10 points contained in the area between ABC (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.)
- Then the node server makes an API call for each origin/dest couple (A1, B1, C1, A2, B2, etc.)

My first design was a complete calculation for each request, which probably won't sustain an heavy load. The new design must be scalable for several users and compatible with a progress bar or a progressive loading.

With the advices of a friend, I started a draft design consisting of :

- POSTing the calculation query to database (with a calcul identifier, which will be used by the front to GET the progress and the results)
- Creating a concurrent queue of n async functions that exec the postgis queries (n=3 ?) :
  check if there's a result in cache*, else exec the postgis query and cache the result, then update the progress
- Creating a concurrent queue of n async functions that exec the API calls (n=30 ?) :
  check if there's a result in cache, else exec the call and cache the result, then insert/update a row in database with the calculation identifier
- Creating a CRON task that checks each second the pending calculations and add them to the right queue

*I still don't know if the cache should be a Redis DB or some tables in my Postgresql DB

I'm a beginner in this kind of design so any advice would be helpful !

Comment: That last bit about a cron task to check each second is probably wrong.  You should be able to just add things to the queue when they arrive or fire off new jobs when other jobs finish.  There should be no reason to be polling every second.

Comment: How big is the cache (in terms of memory usage)?  And, are you clustering your server?  Redis is not a persistent store (unless you add snapshots on top of it) vs. PostgresqlDB which is persistent so that would probably determine which way you need to go based on whether you need persistence of queued jobs if your server crashes.  If persistence is not needed and memory use is not large and you aren't clustering, you can just go simpler and use in-memory Javascript for the cache.